# Full alias for table columns in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, column-alias

I want something like `alias_attribute` for make a full alias for column from DB. For example I have a table with many columns named like `UGLYCOLUMN`.

Using it in a query is very uncomfortable:

```
MyModel.where('UglyColumn'.upcase => 'value')
```

I want some kind of:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  awesome_alias_attribute {'UGLYCOLUMN' => :pretty_column, ...}
  ...
end
```

And then use `MyModel.where(pretty_column: 'value')` instead of `MyModel.where('UglyColumn'.upcase => 'value')`.

Moreover it must work for complex query `MyModel.joins(:other_relation).where(my_models: {pretty_column: 'value'})` and so on.

In a perfect case it must work with all ActiveRecord methods and properties. I.e. if I firstly create an alias for primary key `awesome_alias_attribute :UGLYPRIMARYKEY, :id`, then I want say `self.primary_key = :id` and have a profit.